# Слово, в котором 8 букв и 9 звуков

Tags: фонетика

Задание из учебника по русскому языку для 3-го класса:

> Укажи слово, в котором 8 букв и 9 звуков:
>
> 1. волшебник,
> 2. животное,
> 3. фантазия,
> 4. экспресс.

Первое и последнее сразу отпадают. Остаются 2 и 3, и оба подходят, так как последняя гласная в обоих случаях передает два звука:

- е = йэ
- я = йа

Но должен быть только один *правильный* ответ.

Comment: И 2 и 3 являются правильными ответами, если нужен _один_ правильный ответ, просто выберите любое из этих двух.

Comment: @YellowSky Но, может быть, есть причины, по которым одно из этих слов является предпочтительным. Например, `фантазия` происходит от греческого `phantasia`; я намекаю на то, что звуки `и` и `й` как бы сольются в один.

Comment: В смысле, _фантазия_ произносится как _фантазья_? Это навряд ли. Учебник-то для 3-го класса, какой-то особой лингвистической глубины от него ожидать не стоит. А может это просто ошибка. А может это слово _животное_, потому что в нём все звуки разные, а в слове _фантазия_ звук [a] повторяется.

Comment: Я боюсь, вопрос для 3-го класса может не подчиняться в полной мере логике и нормам русского языка. Например, знают ли уже в 3-м классе про "йотированные гласные"? И я не думаю, что можно говорить о слиянии `и` и `й`. В русском есть чёткая разница между `фантазиа` и `фантазия`. Вот хорошая ссылка по теме: http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200400705

Comment: @texnic - Знают в 3-м классе про "йотированные гласные", иначе никто бы не мог найти правильного ответа.

Comment: Фонетический разбор слова, где рассказывают про *йотированные гласные*, передающие в некоторых случаях *два звука*, проходят еще во 2-м классе.

Comment: Может быть, у слова "животное" предполагается окончание [оэ], а не [ойэ]?

Comment: @YellowSky Оказывается, именно такие углубленные знания о фонетике русского языка ожидаются от учеников 3-го класса. [Ответом будет «фантазия»](http://russian.stackexchange.com/a/1914/33), но мои рассуждения в комментарии выше оказались верными, только применить их нужно было к слову «животное».

Comment: @YellowSky Вариант с тем, что в слове «фантазия» звук [a] встречается дважды, нет — трижды, [всплыл в обсуждении](http://natashapiter.livejournal.com/516266.html?thread=2525610#t2525610). Мы его приняли за верную догадку, и поэтому отметили «животное». Но подвох оказался в другом…

Comment: @Anixx Вы на верном пути, только не [-оэ], а [-аи].

Comment: просто плохое задание

Comment: @shabunc Плохое, именно это и пугает :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Правильным ответом оказалось слово **«фантазия»**. В нем 8 букв и 9 звуков.

Занимательный вопрос, *почему «фантазия», а не «животное»*. Оказывается, в слове «животное» будет 8 звуков:

> [жы'вотнаи]

Потому что на «-ное» не падает ударение, звук [й] исчезнет из редуцированного до [и] сочетания [йэ].

Позже я нашел подтверждение этому в Википедии в статье [Русская фонетика](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) в разделе [Скользящий сонант](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D1.8B):

> - /j/ (/j/) — орфографически **й**, а также в составе йотированных гласных (я, ё, ю, е) не после согласных: йод /jot/, [як](/wiki/%D0%AF%D0%BA) /jak/, ёж /joʂ/, еле /'jelʲi/, юг /juk/.
>
>   - Полугласный аллофон (глайд) [ɪ̯] произносится после гласных, образуя дифтонгические сочетания, которые в русском являются двухфонемными: яйцо [ɪɪ̯ˈʦo], ей [jeɪ̯]. После безударных <и> и <ы> в окончаниях прилагательных в обычной речи не произносится: красный /'krasnɨ/.
>   - /j/ обычно не произносится между любой гласной и /i/: *заяц* /'za.iʦ/ < |za.jaʦ|, *кланяется* /'kɫa.nʲi.iʦ.ʦa/.

Здесь ключевым является последний пункт: */j/ обычно не произносится между любой гласной и /i/.* Таким образом, в соответствии с этим правилом, и правильным ответом должно быть слово *«животное»*, если принять, что «е» редуцируется до [и] (/i/). Но ведь при произнесении явно слышен неопределенный звук /ə/, а не четкое /i/, и звук /j/ ([й]) тоже слышен.

---

При этом в [транскрипции слова «животное»](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5#Pronunciation) в Викисловаре выделено 9 звуков:

> [ʐɨˈvotnəjə]

К данной транскрипции у меня нет никаких претензий: в конце слова мы слышим два [неопределенных звука](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B2%D0%B0), разделенных звуком /j/ ([й]).

К сожалению, для слова [«фантазия»](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F) в Викисловаре нет транскрипции.

---

**Обновлено:** Со слов учительницы, правильным ответом признано слово «фантазия», потому что *«партия так приказала»*. А так в обоих словах одинаковое количество звуков.

Comment: У меня в ЕГЭ похожий вопрос был. Камнем преткновения стало слово "ведь" - речь шла о том, в каком слове есть звук Э...

Comment: @Umari А другие слова какими были? В принципе в этом слове «е» редуцируется до [и]. Вообще очень плохо, что в тестах встречаются подобные неоднозначности…

Comment: Не помню. Это так давно было...

Comment: [жы'вотнаи] -- так никто не говорит :(

Comment: @alamar [партия приказала](http://alexyv.livejournal.com/269828.html) говорить *так*, а против партии не попрешь.

Comment: > [жы'вотнаи]
В самом деле, где можно услышать такой диалект?

Answer (score -1):

Иногда "фантазия" произносится как "хвантазия", "ф" -> "хв".
первая буква расщепляется на два звука.

Comment: Ни разу не слышал такого произношения.

Comment: Действительно, иногда "хвост" произносят как "фост" а "Фёдор" как "Хвёдор". Это диалектные особенности и на подобный ответ вряд ли рассчитывали составители учебника. Есть версия что до появления буквы Ф этот звук изображали сочетанием ХВ, откуда и возникла путаница. Но Ф не содержит в себе звуков ХВ.